Binding an event listener to a dynamic element
I have a component with a containing div set up as follows:
<div class="section-wrapper" ref="wrapper" v-if="dataLoaded"> ... </div>

After the component data is loaded I want to bind an event handler, but I'm struggling to do so.
I call a method that fetches data, I then set dataLoaded to true and have the following:
dataLoaded = true;
const wrapper = wrapper.value;

console.log('wrapper', wrapper);
console.log('wrapper value', wrapper.value);    

wrapper.addEventListener("wheel", (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    wrapper.scrollLeft += evt.deltaY;
});

The event listener can't be added because it seems it can't seem to find the element. When I check my console log I see the following:

So it seems I'm able to log the ref but not able to retrieve the value, and therefore the element. I'm a little confused as to how Vue is handling this and what it is I need to do to access the element and bind the listener.
Is anyone able to help?
EDIT: The reason I need this to be done programmatically is I also need to remove the handler on mobile devices
Thanks

VUE SFC PLAYGROUND
Bind the event directly:
<div class="section-wrapper" ref="wrapper" v-if="dataLoaded" @wheel.prevent="e => wrapper.scrollLeft += e.deltaY"> ... </div>

You also should declare your wrapper as ref:
const wrapper = ref();

Never deference DOM refs like wrapper = wrapper.value since Vue can re-render a component and the reference gets invalid.

Thank you Alex, the only issue worth mentioning is that this functionality only needs to work on larger viewports. The reason I wanted to do it programmatically was so I could remove the handler on mobile devices. How is this possible with your suggestion?

@sterix24 the wheel event just won't be triggered on devices not supporting it. otherwise you could watch the ref watch(wrapper, () => /* assign handler here conditionally */)
